# Change hyperref border color individual

Tags: hyperref

I want to change the border color of my hyperref links depending on an input variable for the `\myLabel` command.

In this MWE all links are colored blue. How can I use a third input variable in my command to tell him to change this color just for a particular label and not overall in the `hyperref` settings?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={0 0 1}]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myLabel[2]{\def\@currentlabel{#2}\phantomsection\label{mylabel:#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\myRef[1]{\ref{mylabel:#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section*{Test Section}
  \myLabel{TEST_LABEL}{TEST-LABEL-TEXT}\\
  MORE TEXT\\
  \myRef{TEST_LABEL}
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. With

   ```
    \usepackage{xcolor}
   ```

   color names can be used instead of raw numbers in `linkbordercolor`.
2. The color can be changed locally in a group with `\hypersetup`, e.g.:

   ```
    \newcommand\myRef[1]{%
      \begingroup
        \hypersetup{linkbordercolor=red}%
        \ref{mylabel:#1}%
      \endgroup
    }
   ```